# T-SQL How to concatenate string field of first n rows in group by statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below:

```
FileHash              FilePath
1                     A.txt
3                     e.txt
3                     f.txt
3                     g.txt
3                     h.txt
2                     B.txt
2                     c.txt
```

In T-SQL, How to concatenate the **first 3** FilePath of each FileHash as follows:

```
FileHash              FilePath
1                     A.txt
2                     B.txt, C.txt
3                     e.txt, f.txt, g.txt
```

Comment: Do some research before asking a question :)

Answer (score 1):

One method:

```
WITH files
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT FileHash
         FROM   dbo.test)
SELECT FileHash,
       Stuff((SELECT ', ' + FilePath
              FROM   dbo.Test AS fp
              WHERE  fp.FileHash = files.FileHash
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS FilePath
FROM   files;
```

Comment: How did you answer after the question has been marked as **duplicate**. I don't see any answering options or answer text box

Comment: Could be a concurrency bug.  I should add that the referenced thread is 5 years old and protected.  It doesn't include the technique using a CTE with a correlated subquery, which is most appropriate here.

Comment: I didn't say anything wrong about the answer:) was wondering how you answered after question been marked as duplicate.

Comment: @NoDisplayName http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/145673

Comment: @MartinSmith - Got it :)